# SQL PIVOT que estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: sql

```
select id, SGA, ZLN, GSI, CON
from (select origen, id from ExpedientesR_2016)
pivot (count(*) for origen in ('SGA' as SGA, 'ZLN' as ZLN, 'GSI' as GSI, 'CON' as CON)) as pv
```

solo marca error cerca de pivot.
'SGA', 'ZLN', 'GSI', 'CON' son los posibles valores de origen.

Resuelto. Gracias por sus comentarios y ayuda.

Comment: Deberías explicar que te sucede, error que te arroja..., vamos proporcionar mas información de la que das, sino seguramente será cerrada

Comment: Faltaría que indiques cual es el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Estás cometiendo tres errores:

1. Debes darle un alias al query de la clausula from.
2. No puedes utilizar count(*), debes contar específicamente alguna columna
3. Utiliza directamente los valores del Pivot como nombres de columna,

Con eso en mente una posible solución sería esta:

```
with 
ExpedientesR_2016 as (
          select 1 id, 'SGA' origen
union all select 2, 'SGA'
union all select 3, 'CON'
union all select 4, 'ZLN'
union all select 5, 'SGA'
union all select 6, 'CON'
union all select 7, 'SGA'
union all select 8, 'ZLN'
union all select 9, 'GSI'
union all select 10, 'SGA'
union all select 11, 'ZLN'
union all select 12, 'GSI'
)
select *
from (select origen, id from ExpedientesR_2016) x  
pivot (count(id) for origen in ([SGA], [ZLN], [GSI], [CON])) as pv
```

Answer (score 0):

Trata así :

```
select *
from (select origen, id from ExpedientesR_2016) as tabla1
pivot (count(origen) for origen in ("SGA" , "ZLN" , "GSI" , "CON" )) as pv
```